# Null Pointer while trying to get Principal User with Okta

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, okta

After logging in on website using Okta for authentication I go to the home page and it gives a null pointer exception when I am trying to grab the logged in User Principal. 
Here is my Security Dependencies: (I am using Spring boot 1.5.6)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency> 


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String home(Model model, Principal principal) {

    System.out.println(principal.getName());

    return "/home";
}
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be great. I have looked at the documentation and it seems I am not doing things incorrectly.

Comment: Do you have `@EnableResourceServer` in your Spring Boot Application class? https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot#create-a-controller

Comment: I did not. Don't know how I missed that. The documentation I looked at didn't have that for some reason. All the versioning seemed to be the same as I am using as well. Either way it works now. Thanks!

Comment: I also have @EnableOauth2Sso on my Security Config though. Shouldn't only one or the other be used?